# Unable to apply array_unique on exploded string

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a few database records which I want to take into an array and some of them are duplicate. I tried filtering them with `array_unique` but it doesn't seem to work on `explode()`-d strings.

```
$string = 'one two three one';
$explode = array_unique(explode(',', $string));

var_dump($explode);
```

The above outputs the following:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'one two three one' (length=17)
```

I also tried using the `str_getcsv()` function as a bit of a workaround but to no avail;

```
array_unique(str_getcsv($string));
```

Results in the same as the above example. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string is space delimited, not comma:

```
$string = 'one two three one';
$explode = array_unique(explode(' ', $string));

var_dump($explode);
```

Comment: Will accept the answer as soon as I'm capable of. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

You're exploding on `,` which isn't present in your string.

Try this:

```
$string = 'one two three one';
$explode = array_unique(explode(' ', $string));

var_dump($explode);
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/172471)

Comment: Both answers are valid. Upvoting this one. Thanks ;)